# What is the correct SQL query for my Index method in the controller

Tags: controller, asp.net-mvc-5

Using MVC 5, VS2015, Database first.

Having a lot of trouble with a SQL statement.  I have searched the internet and cannot find a single article related to this issue.  I'm getting 3 errors in my controller's Index method:

Here's the relavent model for the workorder table:

```
... other table properties
public Nullable<int> packing_slip { get; set; }
... more table properties

public virtual equipment equipment { get; set; }
public virtual sales_order sales_order1 { get; set; }
```

Here's the controller:

```
// GET: Workorders
public ActionResult Index(int acctID = 481)
{
   var workorder = db.workorder.Include(w => w.equipment).Include(w => w.sales_order1).Where(w => w.sales_order1.on_site.Convert.ToChar(sales_order1.on_site) == 'F' && w.packing_slip is null && w.equipment.acct_id == acctID);
   return View(workorder.ToList());
}
```

Here's the errors:

> Code: CS1031  Description: Type Expected  Points to: null in SQL
>   condition
>
> Code: CS1003  Description: Syntax Error, ',' expected Points
>   to: null in SQL statement
>
> Code: CS0103  Description: The name 'w' does
>   not exist in the current context  Points to: last query condition

I suspect the last error has to do with the first two.

(I understand the acctID variable should not be hard-coded... that's my next task!)

TYIA, ~~~Tracy

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out... Very rooky mistake...
I replaced:

```
w.packing_slip is null
```

with

```
w.packing_slip == null
```

All is good now in coding land!
~~~Tracy